# Lenovo ideapad320 laptop(amd a9 processor) touchpad stop working - Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

**Touchpad** work normally for few seconds then stop working. I must use mouse instead. How to fix this problem? First time using linux I have no idea what I,m doing! :)

Comment: I've written an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948). Let me know if it helps or you have questions by adding a comment here using @WinEunuuchsToUnix in the comment

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thank you for your help! I fix the problem with Ukuu Kernel Update Utility. I installed 4.14.13-041413-generic and everything work fine, for now.

Comment: I'm glad the answer worked. You can help others know it works by up-voting the answer there. Thanks for letting me know.